# Is there a git hook that runs on git reset?

Tags: git

I am using a script that runs as `post-checkout` and `post-merge` hook to ensure some permissions on the working copy files.

Neither of these hooks is run on `git reset`, so after a `git reset --hard` the permissions are lost because apparently the files were created freshly.

Is there a hook that runs on `git reset` that I can use to run my permissions script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. :(

This is the full list of hooks from the git documentation, and there's no mention of a reset hook. : https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Comment: There isn't anything in the works, either, according to the latest _What's cooking_.